# Different WCF Bindings, their differences and compatibility with other platforms

Tags: c#, java, php, .net, wcf

I am looking for some good technical details on Topic of WCF bindings, I am interested to know following things.

1. List of Different WCF Bindings with its special purpose and limitation.
2. Compatibility/Interoperability with other platform like consuming WCF service in Java, PHP client. Which binding is supported and which is not.
3. If I want to get/post secure data through service API which binding should I use if client application is in Java or Php ?

I have browsed through different material over internet but it is not in detail and somewhat scattered. Waiting for some good responses.

Comment: I have added another question to get more clarification, Thing is I have to make a service API through which different client can communicate with my application for data input, data processing, Please relate the question with this scenario and provide response.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[Choosing the right WCF binding](http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/10/02/choosing-the-right-wcf-binding.aspx)

[image]

1. **BasicHttpBinding**: Basic web service communication. Exposes WCF services as legacy ASMX web services. Used for interoperability. No security by default.
2. **WSHttpBinding**: Web services with WS-* support. Supports transactions and reliable messaging.
3. **WSDualHttpBinding**: Web services with duplex contract and transaction support.
4. **WSFederationHttpBinding**: Web services with federated security. Supports transactions.
5. **MsmqIntegrationBinding**: Communication directly with MSMQ applications. Supports transactions.
6. **NetMsmqBinding**: Communication between WCF applications by using queuing. Supports transactions.
7. **NetNamedPipeBinding**: Communication between WCF applications on same computer. Supports duplex contracts and transactions.
8. **NetPeerTcpBinding**: Communication between computers across peer-to-peer services. Supports duplex contracts.
9. **NetTcpBinding**: Communication between WCF applications across computers. Supports duplex contracts and transactions.

Comment: +1 for adding the chart, before that you'd only covered half the question.

Comment: Thanks, but i am already gone through this article before posting here, What I am interested in is scenarios/situations where one binding is applicable and other is not, and other question is can i consume all services with Java or php client ?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake - mostly for the other tech lik php,jsp which works in web domain its better to use BasicHttpBinding protocol that easily we can decide form the chart ...that might answer both question...its better to go and read about each protocol because each having description of 1 or 1/2 page which i cannot include here

Comment: @PranayRana however, you could have pointed out that the NetTcpBinding only works with .NET at both ends of the pipe.  The MSMQ bindings sit in the middle (mostly) and the Basic and WS bindings are commonly used for interop with other environments. I agree that the chart _effectively_ does that.

Comment: What does WCF to WCF means?

Answer (score 5):

To add to the accepted answer, if you want to bind your **JSON** request to an object in WCF, use **webHttpBinding**

Answer (score 3):

- If you are required to create a binding that is globally
  inter-operable, use `http` binding.
- For internal use, but consumers are in separate servers use `tcp`
  binding. It less inter-operable, but using binary encoding which is
  faster.
- Use `named pipe` binding for intra-server communication, that is for
  consumers hosted in same servers. Named pipe binding is the fastest
  one in wcf allowed bindings.

Use bindings appropriately, make your project best.