# difference between a http binding and the tcp binding in wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

What is the difference between a http binding and the tcp binding in wcf service.What are the different scenarios we user them and what difference does that make to the application?

Any help would be appreciated..!!!

Comment: Have you done any reading around this topic yet? e.g. http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interview/exam288-what-is-binding-and-how-many-types-of-bindings-are-there-in-wcf.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10849920/1529246

Comment: both the links provided above are actually telling the same thing.. and i am not able to get the proper difference which i can basically tell to interviewer whosoever wl ask me the same..

Comment: The http binding will use the http protocol...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx

Quote from Juval Lowy's book -

"A binding is merely a consistent, canned set of choices regarding the transport protocol, message encoding, communication pattern, reliability, security, transaction propagation, and interoperability"

So, if you can read around these parameters for any of the binding in WCF (including TCP and Http(basic etc.), you should be able to answer and more importantly, wisely choose relevant binding when it comes to application.

Answer (score 4):

**BasicHttpBinding** - main feature: uses WS-I Basic Profile 1.1 standart mainly used for consuming the **old ASMX WebServices**. Other important features, you must pay attention on:

1. Works over http protocol
2. Supports security according to BasicHttpSecurityElement (None/Transport/Message/TransportWithMessageCredential/TransportCredentialOnly)
3. Supports message encoding with Mtom (Message Transmission Organization Mechanism 1.0 (MTOM) encoder), used for tranfer of messages with large binary attachments

**NetTcpBinding** - main feature: uses WS-* standart (has more features then WS-I Basic Profile 1.1) for deploying and consuming of the **.NET WCF services** in cross-machine communication environment. Other important features:

1. Works over tcp protocol
2. Supports security according to NetTcpSecurityElement (None/Transport/Message/Both)
3. Supports transactions
4. Supports reliable sessions (can support exactly-once delivery assurances)